# Can't understand why my app is behaving like this?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

Actually I have programmed an app using kivy, kivymd and python. All went good but when I have converted it into .apk using buildozer and ran it on my android device the GUI seems to be tiny or in box I cant figure out.

Is this happening due to my .spec file ??
.spec file code:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Catalyst

# (str) Package name
package.name = catalyst

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.catalyst

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.1

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET
# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27
# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21
....more code...
```

Edit: I have removed the app code as the problem was in .spec file.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
fullscreen = 0
```

to:

```
fullscreen = 1
```

in your spec file.

Comment: Thanks!! Can I ask you something?

Comment: Sure, ask away.

Comment: Nothing, just resolved the problem :) Thanks again!

Comment: can you please help me with this @John Anderson : https://stackoverflow.com/q/70831953/18016176